# Converting String to Date Object in JavaScript defaults time to 12:00

Tags: javascript

I have a string like 2020-09-30T06:30:00Z

when I try to convert it into Date object it defaults time to 12:00

```js
var d = new Date('2020-09-30T06:30:00Z');
console.log(d);
console.log(d.toString());
```

I am not sure about the reason.

Comment: maybe you should give it also a timeZoneOffset

Comment: It assumes you gave the time in UTC and is converting it to your local timezone.

Comment: Have a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15141762/how-to-initialize-a-javascript-date-to-a-particular-time-zone